# error TS2339: Property 'camera' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, navigator

I am trying to build an Ionic app that takes a picture.
but when i'm running the program i get 'error TS2339: Property 'camera' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

i installed `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`
also `npm install @ionic-native/camera`

this is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { Camera } from "@ionic-native/camera/ngx"; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    Camera,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this is my home.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from "@ionic-native/camera/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"]
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private camera: Camera) {}

  takePicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });

    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
      var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
      this.image.src = imageURI;
    }

    function onFail(message) {
      alert("Failed because: " + message);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But, why are you using `navigator.camera.getPicture()`?

You have to use `this` keyword to access camera object and then you can call `getPicture()` method like `this.camera.getPicture()`.

Comment: camera does not exist on Navigator, check out the docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator

Comment: if i do as you say i get the following error: `error TS2554: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 3`. and i want to say. the camera does work when i run it on my phone but i want to get rid of the error

Comment: How you called the method? You have to call method like `this.camera.getPicture({option:yourOption}).then((result) => {//here is your result}}.catch((err) => {//error});`

Comment: You have passes success and error callback as method, so its not working. Handle success and error callback using `then` and `catch`.